# average character in a given word

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to python and I am trying to write a program that will calculate the average character in a given word.

This is the assignment: Write a program that accepts a word (a sequence of letters) and return the average character.

And the program should flow in this order:
Turn the string into a list of characters.
Use ord() function to convert from character to number.
Calculate the average value of the the number.
Use chr() to convert from number back to character.

I think I am supposed to take an input and then find the integer values using ord() function, and then find the average of those integers.

This is what I have written so far:

```
word = input('Enter a word here:')
list(word)
print(list(word))
for char in range(len(word)):
    print(ord(word[char]))
```

The program can turn the word into a list of characters and also display those integer values. But now, I'm lost and not sure where to go to find the average of these numbers. Can someone point me in the right direction like maybe a website that explains how to do it or something like that.

Comment: Hint: How would you normally find the average of a bunch of numbers by hand? If you can think through the steps you would take, then code to that, you'll have it solved. Also: Instead of `print()`, why not add the numbers to a list to help you work with them?

Comment: @G.Anderson To find the average of a number, I'd add them up and divide by the number of numbers. But uhm to put the numbers in a list I'm not too sure how to do that. Would it be possible to do something like : numbers = (ord(word[char])) list(numbers) that way i can take the integers and then place them into a list?

Comment: See [the python list documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) for more on using lists for this task. Basically, declare an empty list variable, then in your loop `append()` numbers to the list, then do your operations on the numbers saved in the list object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I understood is something like this:

```
word = input('Enter a word here:')
sum_word = 0
for character in word:
  sum_word += ord(character)
average = chr(sum_word//len(word))
print(average)
```

Just got a doubt about `average`, but let me know if it isn't right and I'll change it

Comment: This one works, so thank you, but if you could walk me through on how it works I would really appreciate that! I don't want to just have the answer, but know the process as well :D

Comment: Yep. First of all, `word` is a string variable and if you read Python documentation it's an iterable object so you can iterable each character of it with a for loop. Then you need to get its number equivalent with `ord`, add all of them in `sum_ord`. Last you get the `average` taking a simple average and rounded with `//` and its character representation with `chr`.

Answer (score 0):

The Pythonic way is to use either list comprehension or mapping.

```
word = 'hello, world'
```

With mapping, you tell function `map` to apply `ord` to each character:

```
chr(sum(map(ord, word)) // len(word))
#'`'
```

With list comprehension, you apply the function yourself:

```
chr(sum(ord(x) for x in word) // len(word))
#'`'
```

The mapping solution is about twice as fast as the comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
word = 'hello'
chars = [ord(c) for c in word]
avg = sum(chars)//len(chars)
avg_char = chr(avg)
```

For 'hello', the average character is 'j'.

Comment: This code also works, but if you could explain it to me that would be great too.

Comment: Sure, and please vote for my answer.  The 3 lines after word = 'hello' do this:  1) list comprehension to get the ord(c) for each c in word, i.e., every character in word into a list.  2) average is the normal math of:  total / count.  Use sum() to total all numbers in the list, use len() to find the length of the list.  3) use chr() to convert that average number into a character.